# convert a long string of characters to uint32_t or uint64_t in c++

Tags: c++

I want to convert a string containing alphanumeric characters into either uint32_t or uint64_t.
Tried doing the following. But, I am getting "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range' " error. Also, when the string is smaller in length, for example : string s = "hello", it works, but what if I want to convert a longer string into uint32_t or uint64_t.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

std::string string_to_hex(const std::string& in) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::hex << std::setfill('0');
    for (size_t i = 0; i < in.size(); ++i) {
        ss << std::setw(2) << static_cast<unsigned int>(static_cast<unsigned char>(in[i]));
    }

    return ss.str(); 
}

int main() {
   std::string s = "hello world, this 123";
   std::string hex_str = string_to_hex(s);
   uint32_t value = std::stoul(hex_str , nullptr, 16);
   cout<<value<<endl; 
}
```

Okay, so according to the comments given, is the following the best way to do it?

```
int main()
{
    std::string s = "hello world, this 123";
    std::hash<std::string> hashed_name;
    uint32_t value = hashed_name(s);
    cout<<value<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your example input string produces a hex string `"68656c6c6f20776f726c642c207468697320313233"`, which is WAY TOO LARGE for `stoul()` to fit as-is into an `unsigned long`. It looks like you are trying to **hash** an input string into a number. Using an intermediate hex string is not the way to accomplish that. Hex is just a way to *represent* binary data in a human readable format. It doesn't change the data itself. You need an actual hash algorithm instead, like CRC, MD5, SHA, etc. They take in arbitrary data as input and mathematically convert that into fixed-width numbers as output.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and just `std::cout << hex_str << '\n';` before you attempt that conversion. Now, look at that thing and ask yourself, is there *any* chance this will firt into a platform unsigned-long (which is typically 32bits on x86, 64bits on x64). For the sample data you've provided, `68656c6c6f20776f726c642c207468697320313233` would be the conversion source, which converts to `152575196276689931390365168237947948156825094926899` decimal. No way that fits into either a 32bit or 64bit value.

Comment: What are you going to do with that number? Would you ever want to convert it back to original string?

Comment: @Vlad Feinstein, yeah I might need to do that as well.

Comment: Then hashing is out of the question (it only goes one way). Again, `What are you going to do with that number?`

Comment: @Vlad Feinstein : Pass the uint32_t value to the client, so that they can compare it with the same string "hello world, this 123"

Comment: @rustyx - Convert the string to uint32_t and pass it to the client, and the client needs to verify that the uint32_t passed is same when it as well converts "hello world, this 123" to uint32_t.

Comment: I suggest you consider gmpxx.h, and it's mpz_class.  This class is an arbitrary precision integer, which can easily handle your out-of-uint64-range value.  For instance,  12345! (a big factorial) is 45,141 decimal chars long,  The sizeof(12345) reports as 16 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

This, strictly speaking, does what you need:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

class Converter
{
public:
  static int StringToInt(const std::string& s)
  {
    auto it = cache.find(s);
    if (it != cache.end())
      return it->second;
    cache[s] = count;
    lookup[count++] = s;
  }
  static std::string IntToString(unsigned i)
  {
    auto it = lookup.find(i);
    if (it != lookup.end())
      return it->second;
    return "";
  }
private:
  static inline unsigned count = 0;
  static inline std::unordered_map<std::string, int> cache;
  static inline std::unordered_map<int, std::string> lookup;
};

int main() {
  std::string s = "hello world, this 123";
  int  value = Converter::StringToInt(s);
  std::cout << value << std::endl;
  std::string s2 = Converter::IntToString(value);
  std::cout << s2 << std::endl;
  int  value2 = Converter::StringToInt("hello world, this 123");
  std::cout << value2 << std::endl;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your issue is that the resultant `hex_str` is a MASSIVE number.
Specifically: `0x68656c6c6f20776f726c642c207468697320313233`

You are converting every character to a two-digit hex value (i.e. one byte). Strings of size 4 (8 if using 64 bit int) or more is going to result in a number way too large to fit in your resultant `uint32_t` or `uint64_t`

[See this GDB printout of your program](https://onlinegdb.com/HyooQ1Bwv)

As Remy mentioned in the comments, look into hash algorithms.